# gradle -v not working, executes java instead

Tags: java, windows, gradle, path

I am trying to install Gradle on Windows 10 but I am encountering an error.
I followed all steps specified in the installation guide, but when I try to use gradle (for example gradle -v to check the version) this is the result:

[Screenshot of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGw8e.png)

I am using Java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)

And the Path of both Gradle and Java in the Envionment Variables is set correctly.

[Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHBSm.png)

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Sara, can you please try this command in Command Prompt and share the outcome - C:\Gradle\gradle-7.0\bin\gradle -v

Comment: Hello, the output was hte same in that case, but i was finally able to solve the issue which was in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. After deleting that it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue which was in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. After deleting that it works.